# ActiveSupport Autoloading not working outside of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Given a file structure of

```
lib
  app/
    feature.rb
  app.rb
```

And given the file `app.rb` that consists of:

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/dependencies'

module App
  extend ActiveSupport::Autoload

  autoload :Feature, 'app/feature.rb'

  def self.start
    p Feature.new
  end
end
```

It complains that `LoadError: cannot load such file -- app/feature.rb`

I've tried passing the absolute system path, no path, relative path to `feature.rb` from the module and the relative path from the execution point (one dir above `lib`).

This appears to be exactly the same thing that Rails is doing in the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support.rb).

Seems like this should be pretty intuitive, no?

Comment: Side-point: `File` is a pre-existing constant for Ruby (you know, for opening and closing Files). I'd strongly recommend against calling one of your own classes `File`. Does this problem exist for other-named classes?

Comment: File is not actually the name of the file, I just used it as an intuitive namespace. I will adjust.

Comment: In the source you link to, there's: `require "active_support/dependencies/autoload"` - may or may not help, but worth trying?

Comment: Hmm, I believe the dependencies will pull in everything but I could be wrong. In any case, I did just try that and same problem. Is there a load path I have to change for the project?  Not sure why the absolute link wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is the add the files to the Ruby interpreter load path like this: `$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))`.

What that does is basically, allow Ruby to lookup those files. In Rails that is configured already when a new app is generated.  When building a gem, in the spec you can add files or dirs to the load path. Outside of those, say a script in this instance, you must manually do that. `autoload` does **not** do that by default so you must specify (somewhat confusingly to me) the paths that Ruby can access.

I'm sure someone can clean up this explanation but that is how I understand it.

Comment: This answer is correct and saved me a bunch of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe Rails has `lib` on its autoload paths by default. We've got the following in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

Comment: Rails does not have `lib` in its autoload path. I was attempting to use `ActiveSupport` outside of Rails. But yes, this is what I have done in the past to get it to work inside of Rails.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part. In that case you probably still need to add your directory to autoload paths regardless. Maybe something like: `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths << 'lib/'`. Alternatively, you could probably change your autoload line to `autoload :Feature, 'lib/app/feature.rb'`.